# Gazebo simulator launch file problems - ROS Kinetic

Tags: ros, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to install Gazebo and its proper dependencies in order to simulate a Parrot AR Drone 1. To do this, I used a tutorial from a [Github account](https://github.com/angelsantamaria/tum_simulator). I tried to execute the `roslaunch cvg_sim_gazebo ardrone_testworld.launch` command, but was had the following error:

```
robotics@robotics-2:~/catkin_ws/devel/tum_simulator$ roslaunch cvg_sim_gazebo ardrone_testworld.launch
[ardrone_testworld.launch] is neither a launch file in package [cvg_sim_gazebo] nor is [cvg_sim_gazebo] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

It might have been due to me executing improper commands for my drone when installing the dependencies. I am not sure. I did perform the source command by using `source devel/setup.bash` in the catkin_ws. The command I specifically used for install was

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy-*
```

I am able to find the launch files but ROS can't recognize `tum_simulator` or `cvg_sim_gazebo` as a package. I know this by using the `rospack find <package name>` command. This is probably why I am receiving errors with the launch file. Any help is appreciated, along with recommendations for other simulators known to work in ROS Kinetic for my specific drone.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264816/gazebo-simulator-launch-file-problems---ros-kinetic/) by [Allen Ayala](https://answers.ros.org/users/30618/allen-ayala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2017-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that the `ros-kinetic-ardrone_autonomy` is supposed to be `ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy` (with a hyphen instead of an underscore at the end). Also, I had performed `git clone  https://github.com/angelsantamaria/tum_simulator.git` in `~/catkin_ws/devel`. When I removed it from `../devel` and into `~/catkin_ws/src` the issue with using `roslaunch` was solved!

---

Originally posted by [Allen Ayala](https://answers.ros.org/users/30618/allen-ayala/) with karma: 22 on 2017-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0